# Does the X/Y sperm ratio in male ejaculates depend on circumstances of sex and who they are mating with?

Tags: evolution, sexual-reproduction, adaptation

[Male mice are known to have different X/Y sperm ratios in their testis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8621333/). Possibly, this phenomemon is not limited to the mice. **However, can the males utilise that to their advantage?**

For example, produce ejaculates with higher Y sperm concentration when mating with a female they have not mated before. Or when mating with a female who they perceive as more masculine (regardless of how they do that, be that pheromones, appearance or other signs).

Comment: The Trivers-Willard hypothesis says that females should change the ratio of female-to-male offspring based on her condition (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27170721/). Maybe something similar is happening here, where males ejaculate more X-chromosome carrying sperm when in better health and less when in poorer health. I have never heard of the TWH being applied to males though, so that is honestly just my best guess.